# Share price of Precision Imaging Corporation of America on March 13, 1991

Tags: equities, price

Where can I find the share price of Precision Imaging Corporation of America, Inc. on March 13, 1991?
I realize the company no longer exists and the shares are now worthless but I would like to know how much was spent to acquire 2000 shares in March of 1991.

Comment: Do you know what the ticker was? I searched on Bloomberg & says PNIC was the ticker but couldn't find data under that name or ticker @gar

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this company was traded OTC/Pink sheet (and was already dubious in 1988 see "Precision Imaging Corp"
http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112058759736;view=1up;seq=175).
To my knowledge Compustat database doesn't have it neither.
My next best guess is to try at your library in some old books like "Walker's Manual" or Moody's. 
And my last chance is to go directly to the SEC archives microfilm !

ps: Working for Ameriprise Financial ("PRECISION IMAGING   CORP AMER" 2000)? ;)
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/820027/0000950137-07-012368.txt

Comment: Compustat should have OTC, it just might not be part of the base package.

Comment: I forgot : you can also try datastream (reuters) or Factset!